# PostgreSQL equivalent for RESTRICT ON DROP

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, db2, drop-table

Is there an equivalent function or workaround to realize DB2´s `RESTRICT ON DROP` attribute in PostgreSQL 9.5 or later?

Comment: This is a hack, so I won't put it into an answer.  Create another table and define the PK of the table you want to protect as an FK reference.  Why would you not enforce this with roles/permissions?

Comment: Nice idea, but not an option for about 50+ tables. It´s not a permissions issue. I used that feature in DB2 to prevent people (which have permissions) from "accidently" dropping a table.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: You can add as many columns as FKs to that other table as you want.